# Xamarin Android Equivalent -> Java: Color.Red(int)

Tags: xamarin.android

does anyone know whats the equivalent of:
Java code:

```
int pixel = source.getPixel(x, y);
int g = (int) (0.3 * Color.red(pixel) + 0.59 * Color.green(pixel) + 0.11 * Color.blue(pixel)); //grayscale shade corresponding to rgb
```

In Xamarin Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you're wanting:

```
int pixel = source.GetPixel(x, y);
int g = (int) (0.3 * Color.GetRedComponent(pixel) + 0.59 * Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel) + 0.11 * Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel));
```

This also produces the same result:

```
Color pixelColor = new Color(source.GetPixel(x, y));
int g1 = (int) (0.3 * pixelColor.R + 0.59 * pixelColor.G + 0.11 * pixelColor.B);
```

BTW, there's also GetAlphaComponent():

```
int A = Color.GetAlphaComponent(pixel);
```